# docker --volume format for Windows

Tags: docker, git-bash

I'm trying to take a shell script we use at work to set up our development environments and re-purpose it to work on my Windows environment via Git Bash.

The way the containers are brought up in the shell script are as follows:

```
docker run \
--detach \
--name=server_container \
--publish 80:80 \
--volume=$PWD/var/www:/var/www \
--volume=$PWD/var/log/apache2:/var/log/apache2 \
--link=mysql_container:mysql_container \
--link=redis_container:redis_container \
web-server
```

When I run that as-is, it returns the following error message:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: invalid bind mount spec "/C/Users/username/var/docker/environments/development/scripts/var/log/apache2;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\var\\log\\apache2": invalid volume specification: '/C/Users/username/var/docker/environments/development/scripts/var/log/apache2;C:\Program Files\Git\var\log\apache2': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid mount path: '\Program Files\Git\var\log\apache2' mount path must be absolute. See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

I did a bunch of googling and documentation reading, but I'm a little overwhelmed by Docker, and I think I got it wrong. I tried setting up the container as follows:

```
docker run \
--detach \
--name=server_container \
--publish 80:80 \
--volume=/c/users/username/var/www:/var/www \
--volume=/c/users/username/var/log/apache2:/var/log/apache2 \
--link=mysql_container:mysql_container \
--link=redis_container:redis_container \
web-server
```

It still errors out with a similar error message. If I remove the colon:/var/www it comes up, but it doesn't seem to map those directories properly, that is it doesn't know that `C:\users\username\var\www` = `/var/www`

I know I'm missing something painfully dumb here, but when I look at the documentation I just glaze over. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

For people using Docker on Windows 10, an extra `/` has to be included in the path:

```
docker run -it -v //c/Users/path/on/host:/app/path/in/docker/container command
```

(notice an extra `/` near `c`)

If you are using Git Bash and using `pwd` then use an extra `/` there as well:

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v /$(pwd):/app 09b10e9fda85`
```

(notice `/` before `$(pwd)`)

Comment: after hours of failing to do this all I needed was a / before $(pwd) wow thank you

Answer (score 5):

Well, I answered my own question moments after I posted it.

This is the correct format.

```
docker run \
--detach \
--name=server_container \
--publish 80:80 \
--volume=//c/users/username/var/www://var/www \
--volume=//c/users/username/var/log/apache2://var/log/apache2 \
--link=mysql_container:mysql_container \
--link=redis_container:redis_container \
web-server
```

Should have kept googling a few minutes longer.

Comment: Are you able to access the files now? I tried using this same method but not able to see the windows files.

`docker run -v //c/temp/:/test alpine ls test`
temp.txt

`ls /c/temp`
'Encoding Time.csv'  http1/  netstat.txt  Projects/  selfcheck.json  Stack/  UninstalItems.log
 It appears the docker container has it's own separate and independent copy of the c:\temp directory

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the path relative, you can use pwd and variables. For example:

```
CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd)    
docker run -v /"$CURRENT_DIR"/../../test/:/test alpine ls test
```